# Difference between " ! " and " - " in r

Tags: r, negation

Here is a code snippet, where I'm trying to use `!`:

```
 demo <- <dataframe>[!which(<dataframe>$<col_name> == 0),]
```

but it's not giving me the correct output.

When I use `-` in:

```
demo <- <dataframe>[-which(<dataframe>$<col_name>== 0),]
```

its fetching me the right answer.

Can some one explain why this is so?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is very basic. `!` is logical negation, `-` is (in this case) a unary arithmetic operation. If you apply `!` to integer values `0` is coerced to `FALSE` and all other numbers to `TRUE`: try `!(0:5)`.

Comment: then how about <dataframe>[which(<dataframe>$<col_name> != 0),]  this gives me a right answer

Comment: Well, sure it does. You are aware that R offers logical, integer and character subsetting? And you know what `which` does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So `which` will return a vector of row indices for which `<dataframe>$<col_name> == 0` is satisfied and not a logical (TRUE/FALSE) vector. Hence when you negate that with ! you get nonsense. You are essentially doing this `!c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)` which returns `TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE`.

The `-` sign will remove the rows returned by the `which` statement, which is what you want.

Alternatively you could do:
`demo <- <dataframe>[!<dataframe>$<col_name> == 0,]`

Comment: And if no rows come back you get `data[-integer(0), ]` which will really screw things up ... which is why `which` is a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

Let's take a vector example:

```
x <- c(1, 10, 30, 5)
```

I would like to eliminate all the multiples of 10 in this vector. The vector of booleans corresponding to my condition can be computed like this

```
b <- x %% 10 == 0
```

If I execute `which(b)`, this will return the indices corresponding to the `TRUE` values in `b`, so to exclude all the values that are multiples of 10, I can do

```
x[ -which(b) ]
```

But if I use `!` (the negation operator) on `which(b)` instead of `-` (the command will become `x[!which(b)]`), the result will be completely wrong, that's because the negation operator can be applied on integers without returning an error: if the integer is equal to 0, it will return TRUE, and if the integer is different from 0, it will return `FALSE` (try `!(-2:2)`).

Therefore, if I want the correct result by using `!`, I need to apply it directly on the vector of booleans

```
x[ !b ]
```

Comment: now its clear , I took "!" sign to be as a negation.

Answer (score 1):

`which` returns an index that can be used to positive/negatively index a `data.frame` (or anything else). But `!` a vector of positions will only return `FALSE`s. Try `!5`. Here are some examples:

```
df <- data.frame(col1=1:6, col2=rep(0:1, 3))
> df
  col1 col2
1    1    0
2    2    1
3    3    0
4    4    1
5    5    0
6    6    1

# an vector of positions
> which(df$col2 == 0)
[1] 1 3 5

# ! this vector
> !which(df$col2 == 0)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE

# - this vector
> -which(df$col2 == 0)
[1] -1 -3 -5
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of what is returned:

```
> !which(x = mtcars$cyl == 4)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

> -which(x = mtcars$cyl == 4)
 [1]  -3  -8  -9 -18 -19 -20 -21 -26 -27 -28 -32
```

It is also worth noting:

```
identical(mtcars[!mtcars$cyl == 4, ],
+         mtcars[mtcars$cyl != 4, ])
[1] TRUE
```